# Javascript onKey event && operater

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.onkeyup = function(event){

    var key_press = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = "UP Event Fired For : "+key_press;
    if (key_press == "38") {
        &&
    } if (key_press == "39") {
        &&
    } else if (key_press == "40") {
        &&
    } else if (key_press == "37") {
        alert ("First born beauty");
    }
});
}
```

Hello, I try to make the purpose of this code to action event/popup when arrow keys have been pressed in the right order (left>up>right>down) important that it is body that listens. :)

http://jsfiddle.net/50hup6y1/7/

Comment: Welcome! You forgot to ask a question though. What's the problem you're having with the code?

Comment: Your code isn't even valid Javascript syntax. You can't have `&&` as the entire statement in an `if` body.

Comment: Also, you have an extra parenthesis and brace at the end of the function.

Comment: @Barmar: I think (hope) it's a pseudo-code, or perhaps a profound misunderstanding of using `if (condition1 && condition2)`, but...who knows?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's why OP is asking how to make sure keys are press in specified order. This is just a pseudo code, right.

Comment: Open of your browsers developer tools and you'll be able to see some errors related to your code.

Comment: Set a variable to the previous key codes, and then check if the current key code is the next one in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't mind seeing other responses, but this is, naively, what I came up with:

```
var keyQueue = [];

function checkQueue() {
    // just remove old keys until we only have 4
    // this is to keep the queue from growing too big
    // note the '4' should be the longest combination of
    // keys you plan to use
    while(keyQueue.length > 4) {
        keyQueue.shift();
    }

    if (keyQueue[0] === 37
        && keyQueue[1] === 38
        && keyQueue[2] === 39
        && keyQueue[3] === 40) {
        alert("Hey the keys were pressed in the right order!")
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    keyQueue.push(event.keyCode);
    checkQueue();
};
```

Generally speaking, `onkeyup` stores the key presses in a queue. Then checks to see if the last 4 presses were both the right keys, and in the right order. If so, something happens.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I owe you! I guess i can just change the value 4 to make an infinite 'code'..

Answer (score 1):

My own take on the problem would be:

```
// taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/82548
// attach the .equals method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
    // if the other array is a falsy value, return
    if (!array)
        return false;

    // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
    if (this.length != array.length)
        return false;

    for (var i = 0, l=this.length; i < l; i++) {
        // Check if we have nested arrays
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            // recurse into the nested arrays
            if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
                return false;       
        }           
        else if (this[i] != array[i]) { 
            // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
            return false;   
        }           
    }       
    return true;
}   


// the keys to be pressed, in the order to be pressed:    
var keyOrder = [37,38,39,40],
// the log of keys the user presses:
    keyPresses = [];

function keySequenceCheck (e) {
    // adding the last-pressed key to the array:
    keyPresses.push(e.keyCode);

    // if the keyPresses array is long the key order we're checking for, we
    // we trim off the front of the array:
    if (keyPresses.length > keyOrder.length) {
        keyPresses.shift();
    }

    // checking that the keyPresses array has the same values
    // in the same order as the keyOrder array:
    if (keyPresses.equals(keyOrder)) {
        // if so display the message:
        console.log('Message');
    }
}

// bind the event handler to the <body> element:
document.body.addEventListener('keyup', keySequenceCheck);
```

```js
// taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/82548
// attach the .equals method to Array's prototype to call it on any array
Array.prototype.equals = function(array) {
  // if the other array is a falsy value, return
  if (!array)
    return false;

  // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 
  if (this.length != array.length)
    return false;

  for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
    // Check if we have nested arrays
    if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
      // recurse into the nested arrays
      if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))
        return false;
    } else if (this[i] != array[i]) {
      // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != {x:20}
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}


var keyOrder = [37, 38, 39, 40],
  keyPresses = [];

function keySequenceCheck(e) {
  keyPresses.push(e.keyCode);
  if (keyPresses.length > keyOrder.length) {
    keyPresses.shift();
  }

  if (keyPresses.equals(keyOrder)) {
    console.log('Message');
  }
}

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', keySequenceCheck);
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gsL52xrx/embedded/result).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`Array.prototype.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).
- [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

Comment: Nice, though I do suggest avoiding the ["monkey patch"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes) on `Array.prototype`. Putting that code in a separate object without modifying `Array` would obviously work just as well.

Comment: Hmm, it's not an ideal practice, I agree, but I'd rather do it this way (rather than, for example, `arrayEquals(array1,array2)`). To my mind it comes down to personal preference (and team coding convention, obviously).